# Angular Data in datatable from different calls

Tags: angular

I'm using primeng datatable and a server with Spring Data Rest and HATEOAS, my table depends from 2 different get.
The first call gives me most of the data and the links that I have to use to populate worksession column.
How can I make it works correctly, is it possible to perform worksession calls before datatable displays.
My first response is something like this:

```
{
  "data": [{
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "code": "1111",
      "name": "aaaa",
      "created": "2015-05-22T14:56:29.000Z",
      "updated": "2015-05-22T14:56:28.000Z"
    },
    "_links": {
      "worksession": {
        "href": {"http://........../worksession"}
      }
    }
  }]  
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of second call? a different data based on first response?

Comment: For example first call retrieve the user data and the link to the worksession, to see the worksession in my datatable I have to call these links

Comment: so for each record one service call?

Comment: yes maybe not the best choice, and if I have only 1 call to populate one particular column?